# Origin of "acknowledgment"

Tags: etymology

I was shocked a little while ago to find out that what I assumed was a misspelled version of "acknowled**geme**nt" is not only a correct, but actually the **preferred** US version of the word.

How did "acknowled**gme**nt" come to be a word? I can't even read it.

Comment: http://grammarist.com/spelling/acknowledgment-acknowledgement/

Comment: People tend to shorten words. Life is too complicated otherwise.

Comment: @NVZ Yes, agrd! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acknowledgment%2C+acknowledgement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3

Comment: As Laurel says, there are/were different "rules" for retaining a silent E when adding a suffix.

Answer (score 2):

According to OED, both spellings are actually about the same age, formed from the existing word "acknowledge" plus the suffix "-ment". The earliest citation for the spelling with *e* is 1560, while the earliest without citation for without is 1574 (and both happen to be translations of Calvin's sermons).

1560:

> He will employe all the residue of the life god hath geuen him to make to God acknowledgement thereof, that he might not be found vnthankful.
>   <sub>A. L. *J. Calvin's Serm. Songe Ezechias*</sub>

1574:

> Let vs cast downe our selues before the face of our good God, with acknowledgment of our sinnes.
>   <sub>Arthur Golding [*J. Calvin's Serm. on Job*](http://tei.it.ox.ac.uk/tcp/Texts-HTML/free/A17/A17705.html)</sub>

(It's interesting to note that Arthur Golding, in [this book from 1570](https://books.google.com/books?id=fPxiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq="light+of+true+acknowledgement+of+God.") (another translation), also spelled it "acknowledgement").

---

When the original word ends in "-dge" and "-ment" is added, it's pretty common to have two spellings, one with *e* and one without:

- abridg(e)ment
- grudg(e)ment
- judg(e)ment
- ledg(e)ment
- lodg(e)ment

It's interesting to note that "abbreggement", the original spelling of "abridgment" (from the French word) was always spelled with the *e*. It was not until there was a *d* (when it was "assimilated to the spelling of *abridge*" [OED]) that people began to spell it without an *e*.